# Terminal output is invisible

Tags: haskell, terminal, linux-mint, gnome-terminal, xmonad

I've just installed Xmonad as my windows manager for Linux Mint 16. Its working fine except for one thing, there is no visible output when using terminal.

For example if I launch Firefox via terminal, the program loads up fine. However there is no output in terminal to show I have done this. Its as if the terminal output is being written in black rather than white.

Another example to more clearly illustrate my point, if I press the up arrow key, none of my previous executed input is shown.

I haven't touched any config files, its a clean install of Xmonad.

Any help would be appreciated. Again i've tried searching for the issue on Google but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @CloseVoters: Xmonad is written and configured in Haskell, so problems with configuring Xmonad are problems in Haskell code. Haskell is sufficiently different from most programming languages that problems that appear easy to an experienced coder are insurmountable to others. The Xmonad tag represents a welcome SO-subcommunity of the Haskell SO-community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED. Terminal was changing the output font to black due to the Xmonad settings. Solved by changing the terminal colour scheme to explicit white on black rather than system default.

Comment: It's good practice to "accept" an answer that fixes the problem -- even if it is your own answer. Also, kudos for "branching out" to Haskell.

Comment: @jpaugh One has to wait 2 days to accept his own answer. :)

Comment: @jpaugh Thanks, i'll do so in a couple of days. The more I delve into Haskell the more i'm thinking that functional programming seems to have a lot of advantages. From Haskell, being purely functional, having lazy evaluation and being statically typed all seem to make complete sense to me, although im still very wet behind the ears when it comes to programming languages in general!